# Rest Template GET list and testBuilder method issue Spring

Tags: spring, get, resttemplate

I have a method GET I need to test using rest template:

```
@ApiOperation("Finds all existing Tag")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "When list of new tag has been found."),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "When unable to find any tag"),
    })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Tag>> findAllEvents() {
        log.info("Find All Tags");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(TagEventRepository.findAllEvents());
    }

}
```

my test looks like this:

```
@Test
    public void findAllEvents() {

        //GIVEN
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Tag>> newTag = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Tag>>(){};
        TagTestBuilder
            .withFullList()
            .withSaved()
            .buildList();

            //WHEN
            ResponseEntity<List<Tag>> response = restTemplate.exchange(TagResourceConstants.PATH, HttpMethod.GET, null, newTag);

            //THEN
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(),response.

            getStatusCodeValue());

    }
```

My issue is that I cannot linked parametrized type reference (to proceed with List as a returned entity) to a tagTestBuilder , which creates a full list of tags and extends a TestBuilder abstract class that implements methods such as .createFullList, save and builtList

With the above version the test will pass - but it is incorrect as it is not building proper list of objects I need (not using TestBuilder).

I can of course link list with testBuilder but than I cannot resolve the method of restTemplate exchange such as:

```
List<Tag> newTag = (List<Tag>) TagTestBuilder
            .withFullList()
            .withSaved()
            .buildList();

            //WHEN
            ResponseEntity<List<Tag>> response = restTemplate.exchange(TagResourceConstants.PATH, HttpMethod.GET, null, newTag);

            //THEN
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(),response.

            getStatusCodeValue());

    }
```

I get below error, understand that the form is incorrect, but have no idea how to write it right.

```
Error:(82, 71) java: no suitable method found for exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,<nulltype>,java.util.List<Tag>)
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>,java.lang.Class<T>,java.lang.Object...) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; java.util.List<Tag> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>,java.lang.Class<T>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(java.net.URI,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>,java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.net.URI))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>,org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<T>,java.lang.Object...) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; java.util.List<Tag> cannot be converted to org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<T>))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(java.lang.String,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>,org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<T>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(java.net.URI,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>,org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.net.URI))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(org.springframework.http.RequestEntity<?>,java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.<T>exchange(org.springframework.http.RequestEntity<?>,org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Also tried writing this test using getEntity method and finally this seems to work, but I have to debug test to make sure:

```
@Test
    public void findAllEvents() {

        //GIVEN
        List<Tag> newTag = (List<Tag>) TagTestBuilder
            .withFullList()
            .withSaved()
            .buildList();

            //WHEN
            ResponseEntity<Tag[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(TagResourceConstants.PATH, Tag[].class, newTag);

            //THEN
            assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(),response.

            getStatusCodeValue());
```

I debbug both versions of this test (getEntity with [] and using parametrized type reference and they both seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth argument in `restTemplate.exchage` is `responseType`, and it only tells the `exchange` method to what class the response should be converted. It accepts a variable of type `Class`. It can also accept a `ParameterizedTypeReference`, if the response is a list of objects.

Providing data, i.e. a list of tags in your case, to that argument does not make sense.

Your first code block is right. You don't need to pass a list of `Tags` to the `restTemplate` method

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Tag>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Tag>>(){};
ResponseEntity<List<Tag>> response = restTemplate.exchange(TagResourceConstants.PATH, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseType);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass `newTag` for GET `exchage`?

Comment: I just tried using getEntity without success, and with exchange I finally got to pass the ParameterizedTypeReference<T>  so decided to stick with that. But Your comment made me realized that could be wrong assumption and I decided to use it like I wrote above (getEntity and Tag[].class. Seems to be working :) What do You think?

Comment: I still dont understand why `newTag` is required for calling `getForEntity`. Check the edited answer.

Comment: As far as I am concerned it is needed to compare if my GET request under given url, will response with that precise list of Tag objects I built and saved in a repository for this test. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: No. You would have to compare the return value of the exchange method, with the Tag list from the Tag builder for that.

Comment: The first codeBlock, was technically right, but it was not checking if this exact list of objects will be returned. So I think even if the test passed, it was not correct, since I have created a list, save it and than request for it using GET. As far as I understood parametrizedTypeReference - it was only checking if the list=list, not this precise list I saved, since I could remove by testBuilder and the test was still green (but I have so little experience I might be wrong;) )

Comment: Ok, thank You very much, I will carefully distinguish both versions and read a bit more about it to have a bigger picture of it.